# How to change ender dragon texture resource packs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So yeah, another resource question today. I want to change the texture of the enderdragon so it matches my enderman. But what file do I have to create?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I couldn't find anything on the web, and this may be read, with its answer, in a Google search and may actually help somebody! Couldn't that deserve something better than 2 downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for all questions about where textures are located is to look inside the jarfile and browse through the assets folder.

Ender dragon textures are (along with all creatures) in the `entity` texture folder, inside a folder named `enderdragon`.

Comment: But: How do I name the file? I tried ender.png and enderdragon.png, but it didn't work...

Comment: @AnonymousPi It has multiple images. Did you look inside the jar to see?

Comment: Searched in mob folder...

Comment: Referring back to the second sentence in the answer: `minecraft.jar/assets/textures/` gives you the master model for everything in your texturepack. There's an `entity/dragon/` folder, inside which there are multiple images.

Comment: I only found a folder named -not dragon-, but enderdragon. Don't know if that could work.

Comment: @AnonymousPi Sorry, that's a typo in my answer. Fixed. Basically, when making a texture pack, look through the textures in the jar file, open the images, read the filenames, and just generally look around. It should be self-explanatory if you don't rush. No advice on the internet is a substitute for just taking apart the original and using it as a reference.

Comment: Last question: How do I modify the crystals? I already made the texture in the same enderdragon folder and named it crystal.png but it doesn't work...

Comment: @AnonymousPi Any texture you can see in the game has to already exist. Creating a new file thus won't work, you have to find where it is and overwrite it.

Comment: @Yamikuronue Sorry, I modified an already made resource because I didn't know at the time that you could open the .jar with my I-got-it 7zip (Everybody recommended WinRAR, and I didn't have it)